# value counts problem in a column contained a list (python)

Tags: python, dataframe

`value_counts` can't  count values in list.

Hi,
Some of the `columns` in my `dataframe` have a `list`.

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | `['A']` |
| 200 | `['A','O']` |
| 32 | `['B']` |
| 41 | `['A','AB,'O']` |
| 202 | `['A']` |

When i use `value_counts()` ;  i get this result:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| `['A']` | 2 |
| `['A' , 'O']` | 1 |
| `['B']` | 1 |
| `['A','AB','O']` | 1 |

But i want this results:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| `['A']` | 4 |
| `['O']` | 2 |
| `['B']` | 1 |
| `['AB']` | 1 |

Is there any `code` for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `explode` will work for you

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [['A'], ['A', 'O'], ['B'], ['A', 'AB', 'O'], ['A']]})
df["a"].explode().value_counts()

# output
A     4
O     2
B     1
AB    1

# If your dataframe is like this
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["['A']", "['A', 'O']", "['B']", "['A', 'AB', 'O']", "['A']"]})
df["a"].apply(literal_eval).explode().value_counts()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your answer but it not work. The results is same as past. dtype is object  is it the reason of not working?

Comment: I think your dtype is not correct, because if you run my code it will work, so what you can do let me edit my answer. Check My edit and let me know if this is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the lists, unpack the items (using `itertools.chain`) and then count (using `collections.Counter`) and put it back into a pandas object

```py
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
df['Y'] = df['Y'].apply(lambda x: eval(x)) #converts to list
pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df['Y'].values)))
```

**Output**

```
A     4
O     2
B     1
AB    1
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your answer but it not work for AB .  It gives me A B O.

Comment: You should probably show us what your `df['Y']` looks like - i.e. the output of `print(df['Y'])` to make sure we are using the same input

Comment: dtype is object  is it the reason of not working?

Comment: You can use `eval` to convert the dtype - see edited answer

Comment: Yes , after eval it work! Thanks